# Which libraries are required for Java7 when installing on Debian wheezy?

Tags: debian, java

It is trivial to download and install the Java 7 distribution from Oracle.com.

But I am concerned about any dependencies that might be missing on the system. How can I find out which libraries are required by the java installation?

Previously, when I installed the (obsolete) java6 distribution right from the debian repository, I noticed that a large number of libraries are also installed. So my guess is that Java 7 might require a similar list of libraries.

Here is the output from a java6 installation:

```
# apt-get install sun-java6-bin sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-jre
Reading package lists... Done
dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  avahi-daemon bind9-host dbus geoip-database gsfonts gsfonts-x11 java-common libasound2 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libavahi-core7 libbind9-60
  libcap2 libdaemon0 libdbus-1-3 libdns69 libfontenc1 libgeoip1 libice6 libisc62 libisccc60 libisccfg62 libltdl7 liblwres60 libnss-mdns libsm6 libx11-6
  libx11-data libxau6 libxcb1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxfont1 libxi6 libxt6 libxtst6 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 unixodbc x11-common xfonts-encodings xfonts-utils
Suggested packages:
  avahi-autoipd dbus-x11 default-jre equivs libasound2-plugins geoip-bin binfmt-support sun-java6-demo openjdk-6-doc sun-java6-source sun-java6-plugin
  ia32-sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-fonts ttf-baekmuk ttf-unfonts ttf-unfonts-core ttf-kochi-gothic ttf-sazanami-gothic ttf-kochi-mincho ttf-sazanami-mincho
  ttf-arphic-uming libmyodbc odbc-postgresql tdsodbc unixodbc-bin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  avahi-daemon bind9-host dbus geoip-database gsfonts gsfonts-x11 java-common libasound2 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libavahi-core7 libbind9-60
  libcap2 libdaemon0 libdbus-1-3 libdns69 libfontenc1 libgeoip1 libice6 libisc62 libisccc60 libisccfg62 libltdl7 liblwres60 libnss-mdns libsm6 libx11-6
  libx11-data libxau6 libxcb1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxfont1 libxi6 libxt6 libxtst6 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 sun-java6-bin sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-jre unixodbc
  x11-common xfonts-encodings xfonts-utils
0 upgraded, 45 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 67.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 191 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
...
```

So all of these are required for java6. Please advise which of these are also required for java7. I already got a few responses but I don't think these adequately answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use oab-java to create an apt repository for Oracle Java7. Afterwards you can install as usual with apt-get (or aptitude...), it will certainly pull the required libraries as well.

Get it from here:
https://github.com/tamersaadeh/oab-java

Answer (score 0):

Normally the package by Oracle itself (found [here](http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=78695)) will contain all the needed dependencies or at least download them for you.

After searching further Squeeze does have a Java 7 package called `openjdk-7-jre`. Perhaps that is the package you are looking for. I found it [here](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=openjdk-7-jre).